# missing attribute in activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have models `Foo` and `Bar`. `Bar` has column `foo_id`. 
When I call `Bar.foo_id` I get the error `missing attribute: foo_id`

Keep in mind that this is not an undefined method error and the column definitely is in the db. What are some common causes of this?

Thanks

Comment: How are you loading your Bar?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Probably it has something to do with your **find** method? For instance you did a :select in a find:

```
Foo.find(:all, :select => "firstvar, secondvar")
```

In that case, you can only access firstvar and secondvar even though you have foo_id defined

Hope it helps! =)

Comment: I had default_scope :includes => [:model1, :model2] defined.. instead I used a custom scope with all need includes.

Comment: In my case the issue was that the object had been cached and it was still using the old version that did not have the new attribute.  Once the cache was cleared, things worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Are you calling

```
Bar.foo_id
```

or

```
bar = Bar.new
bar.foo_id
```

Unless you have a class variable for `Bar`, you need to look at `foo_id` on an instance of Bar. I hope that helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me now and then. My cause is almost always a long forgotten finder method on a class that specifies fields in .select() and the missing attribute (often added long after I had the finder defined) is now invoked somewhere in the app but not specified in that .select().

The error is common enough to have earned an alert in the Rails Guides: "[Be careful because ...](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields) "